# SWTBot on OS X and Jenkins

Tags: java, macos, jenkins, swtbot

We have some TCs running on OS X ... and they work fine! 
We've integrated this (OS X) build on Jenkins. That's our problem!

Jenkins log:

```
myTest (com.path.myTest): The widget was null
```

I tried to set "`Run Xvnc during build`" but when the Jenkins build starts it start to run "vncserver" that is not installed on OS X (which has its own VNC server)!

Anyone of you have idea ho to integrate Jenkins with Mac OS X in case a windows session is needed?
Thanks in advance!

Kasper/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the reason:

SWTBot (when running on a CI env) requires:

- Ensure that your session has screensaver disabled.
- Ensure that your session does not 'lock up' after a specified period.

more here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/CI_Server